# How to trigger a doGet before displaying a jsp page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I have a webpage which is named export.jsp, when the user acces domain/export.jsp, I want him to automatically download a csv file via the doGet method of a servlet. Afterwards I want to display the actual jsp file, which is export.jsp

My doGet method is as follows:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/export.jsp");
        //rd.forward(request, response);

        //getting and loading the property file
        Properties propConfig = new Properties();
        Properties propLog = new Properties();

        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            //Loading the property files
            propConfig.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties"));
            propLog.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/log4j.properties"));
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(propLog);

            logger.info("loaded log4j properties From Path: /WEB-INF/log4j.properties");

            connection = DbTools.getConnection(propConfig.getProperty("db_hostname"), 
                    propConfig.getProperty("db_port"), propConfig.getProperty("db_serviceName"),
                    propConfig.getProperty("db_userName"),propConfig.getProperty("db_password"));

            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM QACOMPLETE_DEFECT");

            File csvfile = FileTools.generateCsvFile(rset);


            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+csvfile.getName()+"\"");

            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(csvfile.getAbsolutePath())));
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("SQLException", e);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOexception, The user may have cancel the download ", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            DbTools.closeQuietly(stmt);
            DbTools.closeQuietly(connection);
        }
    }
```

my web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DefectExporter</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DefectExporter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>exporter.DefectExporter</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DefectExporter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/export.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Because when I enter the url `http://localhost:7001/DefectsExporter/export.jsp` in a browser, the doGet method is triggered but the web page export.jsp does not appear.

Comment: First of all, your servlet doesn't forward to the JSP (the two lines that do it are commented out). But even if it did, you've mapped the servlet to the URL of the JSP, so forwarding would invoke the servlet again. Map the servlet to **another** URL, and forward to the JSP in doGet(). But then again, since your servlet already sends CSV to the response, you can't also send HTML in the same response. So, in fact, you should tell us what you're trying to do, because it doesn't make much sense at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Maybe I should reformulate : I want to be able to download the csv file once the link: http://localhost:7001/DefectsExporter/export.jsp is entered in a browser, once the download is executed, i want to display the actual jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, at least without Javascript.

A ServletResponse can do only one thing : either return csv data, or return an HTML page. You absolutely need 2 different requests (be them simple normal requests or javascript one) : first to download a csv file, second to display the JSP.

The only way I can imagine to meet such a requirement would be that servlet sends a page that through javascript, and client side, first download (and save) the csv file and then using a different URL sends a request for the JSP page. BUT AFAIK, there no way to do that server side.